# Trying to clone an AWS Aurora cluster using Terraform doesn't clone the instances, only the cluster

Tags: terraform, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to set up a PoC of cloning an aurora cluster with Terraform using copy-on-write.
Creating the source cluster works fine, and if I clone the cluster using the console it works correctly, creating the new cluster along with the instances.

When I attempt to create the clone using Terraform it creates only the cluster, with zero instances belonging to it. I'm using the restore_to_point_in_time object inside my clone resource, and specifying "use_latest_restorable_time".

Cluster is MySql.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier            = "my-cloned-cluster"

  restore_to_point_in_time {
    restore_type = "copy-on-write"
    source_cluster_identifier = "arn-of-source-cluster"
    use_latest_restorable_time = true
  }
}
```

I tried the other configuration option (replication_source_identifier), but that seems to be specifically for read-only replicas, which is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: When you clone through the UI it is doing a lot of things for you in the background. Your Terraform code is just running one single API command against AWS to create a copy of the data in a new cluster. So you have a cluster with a copy of the data now, but no running instances to serve that data yet. The answer below, regarding adding instances to the new cluster, is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

this just sets up the cluster. you need to additionally define what instances you want running on the cluster.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count              = 1
  identifier         = "instance-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.default.id
  engine             = 
  instance_class     = 
  availability_zone  = 

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And those instances will be clones of the instances from the cluster source? I assumed cloning the cluster would include the instances (as it seems to in the console)

Comment: @cloudiator-person no, cloning just clones the data. for most use-cases, cloned instances will have different sizing requirements than the source.